# Any swift code editors supporting OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, swift

I wanted to get some code editors supporting Swift,
but as I tried to install AppCode or Xcode, I couldn't continue,
because my OS X version is 10.6.8 but these editors only support 10.9.4 or later.
Any suggestions? Thank you.
Edit: (Do you know any editors supporting my version?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift was introduced in Xcode version 6.  Version 6 requires Mac OS 10.9.4 like you said.  You aren't going to find anything for a version of Mac OS that old.

I think there are web-based services that allow you to access newer Macs.  That may be your only hope.

Comment: I will have a look. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can now install VirtualBox on your Mac and install Linux in VirtualBox. This allows you to run Swift on older versions of Mac OS X or even on Windows besides Linux. [You can find binaries for Ubuntu here.](https://swift.org/getting-started/#installing-swift)